# How can a scrollpane of jtable show whole data vertically without scrolling

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I have a Jtable and it enclose in a default scrollpane. When my table grow up with its row, a vertical scrollpane appear. But i don't want it. How can i show whole row vertically without vertical scrollbar.

[image]

Comment: A horizontal row vertical? Your question is hard to understand. Remove the ScrollPane or set the  [verticalScrollBarPolicy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#verticalScrollBarPolicy) to ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER?

Comment: If i remove scrollpane...header of Jtable gone. If i set ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER than vartical scrollbar gone but jtable would not resize vertically respect with its row...@Stefan

Comment: I wan't my jtable will show all row .... why it's not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After loading the data into the TableModel you can set the preferred size of the viewport:

```
JTable table = new JTable(model);
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
```

Comment: Thanks @camickr .. you save my time :)